# How can meaning be represented?

Tags: formal-semantics

How can I represent the semantic content of a sentence or a word in a formal way? So far, I only know that you can use sets of features, but what are the alternative theories?

Comment: This question is too broad. "How can I represent meaning in a formal way" is what entire books deal with. You should make your question more specific in order to make it answerable within a few paragraphs.

Comment: For recommendations on introductory semantics textbooks, see [here](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9928/13238)

Comment: Think about [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). It's designed for representing propositions (statements that can be true or false under some circumstances), and it can be [extended to represent syntactic structure](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), as well.

Comment: There's also Jackendoff's conceptual semantics.

Comment: As I understand, semantics is not directly related to topic extraction. I mean, semantic content of a sentence can be researched in terms of an emotional value, or of word sense disambiguation, or something else, but I want to research exactly extraction of the topic of a message. What can I read about it? I've read some russian books about general semantics, but found nothing about that.

Comment: If you want to extract the topic of the message, you need a **very** strict all-encompassing machine-washable definition of "topic of the message" to train with. _Topic_ is not a very exact term in current use, and ranges anywhere from one-word to sentence to paragraph level. Indeed, it may use words that don't appear in the message it's "extracted" from.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks for the answer! Basically, I'm doing a research for my university about classifying text messages in two classes: related and unrelated to the context of a discussion. I guess, the class depends on the synsets of the primary clauses. So, I thought that is a problem of a topic extraction, but, generally, I don't know how to approach this problem.